# Loading Code onto GPU (Intel Sandy Bridge)

Tags: c, assembly, gpu, intel

My question is not about GPGPU. I understand GPGPU pretty decently and that is not what I am looking for. Intel's Sand Bridge has supposedly some features that allow you to directly perform computations on the GPU.

Is that really true?

The code I am planning to write is going to be in inline assembly (in C). Are there assembly instructions that instead of executing on the CPU push stuff out to the GPU?

Some related documentation :

- http://intellinuxgraphics.org/documentation.html
- http://intellinuxgraphics.org/documentation/SNB/IHD_OS_Vol4_Part2.pdf

The PDF has the instruction set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your first question: No it is not true.

Let me quote from the resources you have linked:

> The Graphics Processing Unit is controlled by the CPU through a direct interface of memory-mapped IO
>   registers, and indirectly by parsing commands that the CPU has placed in memory. (Chapter 2.2 from the SB GPU manual)

So no direct execution of GPU code in the cpu context.

For your second question: "Pushing stuff out to the GPU" is done with the mov instruction. Target is a mem-mapped IO register, source the stuff you want to write. You might need to insert some "sfence" or similar instructions to make sure no weak memory reordering does happen.

Comment: This is going to sound incredibly stupid, but the part that you have quoted, in which manual did you find it? So I am guessing what I need to do is actually "place those commands in memory" via the CPU (?)

Comment: Volume 1, Part 1 - the very first on the page you linked. You use the CPU to place the GPU code you want to execute somewhere in memory. Almost the same as loading an executing a program for the CPU.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that the instruction set detailed in the PDF you linked can be directly used from "user space". It's what the GPU driver on your OS may* use to implement higher-level interfaces like OpenGL and DirectX.

For what it's worth, the Sandy Bridge GPU is pretty weak. It doesn't support OpenCL**, which is a standard GPGPU library which is supported by ATI / nVidia. I'd recommend that you program to that library (on hardware that supports it), as it's far more portable (and easier to use!) than trying to program to the bare-metal interface that you're looking at.

---

*: It's possible, although unlikely, that there's a different interface than what's described in that PDF which is used in Intel's closed-source drivers.

**: Not the same as OpenGL, although it was designed by the same group.

Comment: where did you see SNB GPU supports OpenCL ?

Comment: My mistake; it doesn't. Corrected.